# MAUI multiple platform support

Tags: .net, blazor, maui, avaloniaui, blazor-hybrid

I would like to upgrade some desktop apps to use the latest .net technology to support multiple platforms.  After some research, I know my choices are MAUI and Avalonia.  Here are my findings:

- Both use XAML
- MAUI can create native desktop, ios, android app only.
- Avalonia can create desktop, ios, android, linux and web(WebAssembly) app because it use its own renderer and so the UI will be the same on each platform
- Since Avalonia app are not native, the app may not fully take advantage of each platform
- Avalonia is not from Microsoft.
- Microsoft has Blazor which uses razor and c# in html, mainly for web development. To run Blazor web app in desktop(Blazor-hybrid app), you need to host it in in a WebView desktop component.

For my goal of development of mainly a desktop app, I love the idea of Avalonia because using a single codebase, it produces apps for desktop, mobile and web platforms.  However, I am worrying about the supports of the framework in long term.  I cannot invest on a framework with an unknown future.
I wonder if there is any plan from Microsoft or existing compiler/renderer to let MAUI able to produce a webassembly app?  As I see Microsoft is putting a lot effort in the Blazor-hybrid app development, is Microsoft hopes we use Blazor(razor+c#) over XAML?
Any idea or suggestion is appreciated.

Updated(230828).  MAUI can now support using razor syntax. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WeDw37VNF8Y  Will Microsoft make desktop and mobile apps the same codebase with Blazor?

Comment: *"Since Avalonia app are not native, the app may not fully take advantage of each platform"* - Not correct. See [Dealing with multiple platforms](https://docs.avaloniaui.net/docs/next/guides/building-cross-platform-applications/dealing-with-platforms). There is a third option: Use .Net 7 (soon 8) directly. On each platform, write UI for that platform, in c#. This is the migration of "Xamarin Native", which skips the "Forms" part of "Xamarin Forms". Very reliable. Very long-term. BUT have to write UI separately for each platform, using that platform's APIs (from c#).

Comment: Actually this issue is not very important to me because I believe most of the apps are not very platform specific.  My concern is the way to use one codebase to produce app for PC, mobile and Web Assembly.

Comment: I understand. If Microsoft had decided to back Avalonia (I wish they had), that would be my preference. I personally can not see picking a technology that is not backed strongly by a company that will be around long-term. Blazor is good, if you like coding to web standards. The other c# .Net alternative is Unity. From what I hear, it is good for more than games. And that is a company that backs its technology well (see all the tutorials and learning resources), has strong investor backing, and is aiming for VR/AR. See [Unity / UI toolkit](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UIElements.html).

Comment: I have the same view with you.  I updated the question my new findings

Comment: *"Will Microsoft make desktop and mobile apps the same codebase with Blazor?"* - the level of compatibility is "a Razor component" (or a library of such components). [OPINION] The technical differences between a browser-based "Web App" and a mobile/desktop "Blazor Hybrid" app are such that there is no motivation to attempt to make a single "app package" that is capable of running in both environments. Make two separate "main" projects; one for web, one for hybrid (mobile/desktop).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> MAUI can create native desktop, ios, android app only.
> Avalonia can create desktop, ios, android, linux and web(WebAssembly)
> app because it use its own renderer and so the UI will be the same on
> each platform

Not quite. MAUI can build for MAC too, and if you really want wasm, Blazor is there to cover that too.

> Since Avalonia app are not native, the app may not fully take
> advantage of each platform

MAUI apps are not that great for native development as well. You will have to write a lot of platform specific code. And a lot of #ifdefs. If native capabilities are your main target, then go native, do not go MAUI.

> Avalonia is not from Microsoft.

MAUI being from MSFT does not mean anything. This platform was released (and still is) bug infested. And relies not on MSFT, but the combined community efforts to make it working somehow. (Yes, somehow. Xamarin deja vu anyone?) Can you say "5000 open issues"?

> However, I am worrying about the supports of the framework in long term.

You never know. Lets not forget the "technology of the future" (aka Silver Light) that was promoted as the real deal, and ended up being 3 day miracle. (One of the many techs, along with Windows Mobile, that I want to crack my head open to forget...)

There is no right decision here. I go with MAUI, because right now it makes me "spam" projects. If you think Avalonia will let you develop faster and easier, please go with it.

Answer (score 0):

Maui: Use the xaml to render the UI base the on the native platform library. So it can create native desktop, ios, android app.

Maui-Blazor: Use both xaml and (razor+c#) in the project. It will also has at least one xaml in it which contains the webview. The razor page will render in the webview and the other part will still depend on the native platform library. It seems more like embed the WebAssembly in the native application.

There is no way for maui to create desktop, ios, android, linux and web(WebAssembly) app with one project. It will create native app for all the platforms.

So you can choose the framework depend on your request.